# How to preg_replace all links to images (with and *without* https?)

Tags: php, regex

I am using [Regexpal.com](http://www.regexpal.com/) and I saw this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)

I am trying to NOT match a string.

I need to preg_replace all occurences of links to images with the string 
`<<IMAGE:{link}>>`.
So I was thinking to use `(https?:\/\/)?\S*(jpg|png|jpeg|bmp|gif)` `OR`ing with the same thing but *`without`* the preceding (https?://)

so that:

```
Hi there this is an image link https://facebook.com/images/2323.jpg
and this one is too mysite.org/1.png
```

would become that:

```
Hi there this is an image link
<<IMAGE:https://facebook.com/images/2323.jpg>> and this one is too
<<IMAGE:mysite.org/1.png>>
```

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario OR'ing with *no* (https?)

Comment: What do you mean with "trying to NOT match a string"? Apart from that, there're already [many questions on the subject](https://www.google.com/search?q=stack+overflow+php+find+urls+in+text).

Comment: It's  a block of text, not a link that needs parsing

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong link, removed the comment later and added a new comment with the right link.

Comment: What output do you exactly want?

Comment: Sorry, edited the post. @Ashwini Agarwal, following "would become that"

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this...

```
$str = 'Hi there this is an image link https://facebook.com/images/2323.jpg
and this one is too mysite.org/1.png';

$regex = '/((https?:\/\/)?\S*(jpg|png|jpeg|bmp|gif))/';

$str = preg_replace($regex, '<<IMAGE:$1>>', $str);
echo $str;
```

**Output**

```
Hi there this is an image link <<IMAGE:https://facebook.com/images/2323.jpg>>
and this one is too <<IMAGE:mysite.org/1.png>>
```

**[Codepad](http://codepad.org/L5bErII5)**

Comment: This looks good, but it matches dsfhttps://facebook.com/images/2323.jpg too which is not a valid link!